# Mysql Primary key Deletion and re-insertion

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Are there any known ramifications to manually inserting a record with a primary key that once existed but was deleted.  Said primary key existed only in one table, and is not referenced in any other tables.

Comment: Even though the main reason not to do it is referential integrity, it's never really good practice. Do you need to do it on a frequent basis? Why?

Comment: We have a testing and live server. Records were duplicated on testing, by accident, and had to be deleted.  This caused our live and testing primary keys to be out of sync.  So now we're deciding whether to leave empty rows in the db, or just manually insert into the gap to keep synced up.  I inherited a very badly designed legacy system, so i'm aware that the db this is a sub-optimal situation, but it's what I got to work with.  Thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

But generally it would be a bad idea because of history tables. At some point, it did exist and will be logged in most systems. 
You may also have an external trace: a backup, a copy of the database, some data on a linked server.

If you are just filling gaps in an autonumber or identity, then this is not a valid reason.

Answer (score 0):

you use simple [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement with providing your primary key value, for example:

```
create table some_table (
id int(10) unsigned primary key,
data text
);

insert into some_table (id, data) values (1, 'some data');
```

Comment: I'm sure OP knows *how* to do it: they asked "is it OK"?

Comment: I think OP knows *how* to do it but wants to know if it's good practice to do so.

Comment: depending on circumstances :) seriously, I am sorry, I didn't understand question correctly